# What is the Ehrensmann connection of QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I've heard that QED can be described (at least classically) as a $U(1)$ principle bundle.

Given a principle $G$ bundle $\pi:M\rightarrow B$, an Ehresmann connection is defined to be a collection of parallel subspaces $H_p$ of $T_pM$, where by a parallel subspace $H_p$ of $T_pM$ we mean $H_p\oplus V_p=T_pM$, where $V_p$ is the vertical subspace defined as $\text{ker }d\pi_p$.

My question is: is it true that the $U(1)$ principle bundle is just the product bundle $\mathbb{R}^4\times U(1)$? What is the Ehresmann connection in the case of QED?

Comment: As for the second question, a connection can be equivalently described by a connection one-form. A connection one-form in turn is specified in local trivializations of the bundle by a Lie algebra valued one-form in spacetime which is the gauge potential from QED. So the principal bundle connection is actually the (global) geometric structure underlying the gauge field.

Comment: @Gold So what is the explicit connection one-form in QED?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing about this is specific to *quantum* electrodynamics, this is purely classical: The gauge field of electrodynamics is the [four-potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential) $A$, which when viewed as a 1-form is the [connection form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection#Definition_via_a_connection_form). The "Ehresmann view" of connections as subspaces and not forms is rarely used in physics, but it is of course equivalent to it.

$\mathrm{U}(1)$-bundles over $\mathbb{R}^n, n>2$ are always trivial because $\mathrm{U}(1)$-bundles over $M$ are [classified by $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_bundle#Classification).